# jquery hide load url

Tags: php, jquery

how to hide load url in jquery?i want to hide pmscount.php

```
{
$('#notification').load('pmscount.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
```

Comment: The question to ask here is **Why?** :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Because the script is sent to the client, they will always be able to read it.

You could try obfuscation or encryption methods, but ultimately it will be sent to the client. You might want to try different methods of security such as checking your inputs.

If you want a quick and dirty check to make sure only AJAX is requesting the page, you can check if the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` is set to `XMLHTTPRequest`, as most popular AJAX clients such as jQuery send this header when they make an AJAX request,  but this is spoofable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide it, but you can obfuscate it, which can make it hard to read.

However, obfuscation is **not** really hidden or secure, so you shouldn't use it for real security purposes.

If you are just interested in making it hard (but still possible) to read, you can use something like this [obfuscation tool](http://discogscounter.getfreehosting.co.uk/js-noalnum.php) to make the url hard to read.

This is difficult to read, but is still trivial to decode (someone can just evaluate it using any javascript environment).

If you **really** need it to be secure, you should make the request on the server side, not via javascript.

Comment: Not only is it not secure, it's adding obfuscation at the wrong level. Just open Firebug's Net tab and you can see all the real connections going on in real time.

Comment: @deceze, yes you are correct, it's basically worthless, but it's about the best you could do on the clientside.